# Rails f.date_select html_options no effec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add a custom css class to my date_selects in Rails 4.2.1

But the html_options tag has no effect.

code looks like this:

```
<%= raw t("settings.pause", :pause_starts_on => f.date_select(:pause_starts_on, :include_blank => true, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :start_year => Time.now.year, :html_options => {:class => "form-control"}).force_encoding("UTF-8"),
                    :pause_ends_on => f.date_select(:pause_ends_on, :include_blank => true, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :start_year => Time.now.year, :html_options => {:class => "form-control"}).force_encoding("UTF-8"))
          %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `:html => {:class => "form-control"}` without the `_options`